# C++: Initialising an object of a parameterized class inside another class

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I want to write a C++ program in which an object of a parameterized class A-'a' has to be initialized inside another class B. I should not/can not initialize like 'A a(parameter list);' of class A while declaring the object variable 'a' which is outside the constructor of class B. The necessary parameters to the object 'a' are gotten through the constructor of B. How to initialize 'a' inside B's constructor with the required parameters?

```
Class A{
public:
    A(string s)
    {cout<<s;}
};

class B{
private:
    A a;
public:
    B(string path){
        a(path);
    }
};
```

With the above code I am getting errors. How to initialize the object a(path) inside the class B?

Comment: You are likely looking for [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#:~:text=Member%20initializer%20list%20is%20the,member%20initializers%20must%20be%20specified.)

Comment: I read it four times and I'm not yet sure what your exact setup is. Could you provide a dummy piece of code or pseudo-code for your problem?

Comment: @GuillaumeGris I have tried to explain the question a bit elaborately. Could you please check it out now?

Comment: Ok, looking at your clarification, Igor's comment is probably the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#:%7E:text=Member%20initializer%20list%20is%20the,member%20initializers%20must%20be%20specified.). In your example it would be used like this:

```
class B{
    B(string path) : a(path) {
    }
};
```